# How to easily move all notes to another folder?

Tags: macos, catalina, notes.app

A co-worker resigned last week, and just returned his Macbook to the office.
Now I'm backing up all the data before deleting his Mac account.

He had plenty of notes stored in the Notes app. I don't see a feature to export multiple notes to a zip file or Google Drive/Dropbox/etc. Sharing each one of them via email will be tedious.

I wonder if it's possible to move them to USB flashdrive, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app named [Note2Txt](http://toolsandtoys.net/note2txt-export-apple-notes/) which will convert all your notes to a text file. One file for each note. it runs very fast and you can store the text files wherever you like.  It works fine normally but i had a problem with it on Catalina.

There is also an app named [Exporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/exporter/id1099120373?mt=12) which will convert all your notes to Markup files. Again you can put the output to any folder you like and have write permissions.

Both of these apps will convert all your notes to files. You can use the Notes app to convert a single note to a PDF but that doesn't run in batch mode.